# matplotlib python change axis

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have little problem with axis change.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

im = plt.imshow(np.flipud(plt.imread('tas.png')), origin='lower')

plt.show()
```

I had loaded the image and got axis for my image. For X(0-800)&for Y(0-600).
I don't need such as scale all what i need it is a image as background for my plotting with coordinates which on another axis X(35 77) Y(0 16)
But when i wrote

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

im = plt.imshow(np.flipud(plt.imread('tas.png')), origin='lower')

plt.axis([35, 75, 0, 16]) 
plt.show()
```

I got only the small part of image. Could anyone help? I would be so grateful for some help.

Comment: note that if you're importing pyplot and numpy, the pylab import is totally unnecessary and clutters/confuses your namespace

Comment: Can you post a link to the image somewhere? It's hard to help you without being able to run your code verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `extent` keyword:

```
im = plt.imshow(np.flipud(plt.imread('tas.png')), 
                origin='lower', 
                extent=[35, 75, 0, 16])
```

[`imshow` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow).

Comment: tcaswell, thank you again for your answers) extent helped with axis but image was changed. This is the link [IMG]http://i46.tinypic.com/6nseaa.png[/IMG] .And here is what i exactly need [IMG]http://i50.tinypic.com/6ghjjd.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: @ProtossReed It looks like you just need to play around with the aspect ratio. `imshow(..., aspect=3.2..)` or what ever you need it to be to look right.

Comment: you are genius!))Thanks a lot))aspect helped!

Answer (score 1):

With the following code

```
fig = plt.figure()
extax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
extax.imshow(np.flipud(plt.imread('pnggrad16rgb.png')), origin='lower')

ax = fig.add_axes([0.2,0.2, 0.6, 0.6], axisbg='none')
ax.plot([1,2,3], [3,6,1], color='w')
```

I get this figure [image: this figure].

You should than play with visibility of axis, ticklabels and ticks of `extax` to hide the all the unwanted things of the background image. Should be possible to add a axes with the underlying figure coordinates: give a look [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). The [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) can also give some idea on what is possible and how to do it

The underlying image is taken from [here](http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png)